# Bootstrap side by side buttons no gap when buttons rearrange on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, responsive-design

So I am able to get two buttons side by side just fine, but when the screen is too small the buttons rearrange from top to bottom (like they should), but the problem is there is no gap between them, for example this is what my buttons look like on a  'normal' sized screen

[Example picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jISFa.png)

But on a small device it looks like this

[Example picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q2bg.png)

As you can see there is now no gap between the buttons when they have rearrange from top to bottom on a smaller device, is there any way to fix this?

Here is a snippet of the HTML used

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">btn example 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">btn example 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put some `margin` to each `.btn` and you really should be using [Bootstrap's flex utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/) to handle alignment of the buttons.

```css
.btn {
  margin: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="d-flex justify-content-around flex-wrap">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">btn example 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">btn example 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">btn example 3</a>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">btn example 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">btn example 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">btn example 3</a>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">btn example 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">btn example 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">btn example 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can add just `margin` in css, then between your buttons will be margin:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">btn example 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" style="margin:3px;" role="button">btn example 2</a>
</div>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8B4Wifa8aTqVaFaZcasg?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Add the following class to your buttons.

```
.my-sm-1
```

Or the following, to the last button

```
.mb-sm-1
```

And that's it!

> More info https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote and accept this so it can help others. thnak you